# Use delegates to choose function at runtime

Tags: c#, delegates

I am new to C# and still understanding the concept of delegates. What I know of delegates is that delegates define a function signature and functions with the same signature can be added to that delegate.

```
public class ss
{
    public delegate void sampleDelegate();

    public ss()
    {
        sampleDelegate s1 = new sampleDelegate(sampleMethod);
        s1+= new sampleDelegate(sampleMethod2);
        s1();
    }


    public static void sampleMethod()
    {

    }
    public static void sampleMethod2()
    {

    }
}
```

In the above code I create a delegate and give it sampleMethod and sampleMethod2.  When I call s1() it calls both sampleMethod() and sampleMethod2().

What if I want to only call one of those methods and that decision is to be made at runtime?

I may be missing something very small but delegates are really confusing to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegates are like pointers to a method. At run-time, there's nothing that differentiates calling a delegate or a method excluding that a method is a member of an object:

```
some.Method();
someDelegate();
```

The goal of delegates is creating a *blackbox* where you expect some code to put some behavior, and you simply rely on a method signature.

At the end of the day, they're like *method interfaces*:

```
// It must be a parameterless method which returns no value
public delegate void Action();

// vs

// It must be a class which implements a parameterless method "Do"
// which returns no value
public interface Action
{
    void Do();
}
```

That is, a method can't be conditionally be switched with other, but you need to use regular control flow blocks like `if` or `switch` to take decisions about *what to do*.

In order to don't duplicate Jon Skeet's answer, I'll add another possible solution:

```
    string text = "";

    sampleDelegate s1 = () =>
    {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
         {
             SampleMethod1();
         }
         else
         {
             SampleMethod2();
         }
    };

    s1();
```

Check that, instead of creating two instances of `sampleDelegate` you can create *one that handles the conditional logic to either call `SampleMethod1` or `SampleMethod2`*.

The whole `() => { }` thing is called *anonymous delegate*.

It can be also expressed as follows:

```
    string text = "";

    sampleDelegate s1 = delegate()
    {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) 
         {
             SampleMethod1();
         }
         else
         {
             SampleMethod2();
         }
    };
```

But don't use above syntax... It comes from the old .NET days (.NET 1.0/1.1/2.0).

In summary, **a delegate could or could not be provided as an actual class method, but you can combine class methods with anonymous delegates to meet your needs**.

> What if i want to only call one of those methods and that decision is
>   to be made at runtime? I may be missing something very small but
>   delegates are really confusing to understand.

Actually **this is the reason to use delegates**, but you're right when you say you're missing something.

Delegates are used to situations like the following one:

```
public void DoStuff(string text, Func<string, string> textFormatter = null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(textFormatter != null ? textFormatter(text) : text);
}
```

You might call `DoStuff` either this way `DoStuff("hello world")` or `DoStuff("hello world", text => $"<strong>{text}</strong>")`.

`DoStuff` method implementation doesn't know how to format the given text, **and you provide an optional parameter to give a delegate as argument that will receive the whole text to format and it will return the formatted text.**

Isn't this some way *conditional* after all? Based on the caller, `DoStuff` formats the text in a custom way. You can even provide a default format:

```
public void DoStuff(string text, Func<string, string> textFormatter = null)
{
    // We'll give a default formatter if none is provided ;)
    if(textFormatter == null)
      textFormatter = text => $"<span>{text}</span>";

    Console.WriteLine(textFormatter(text));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> What if i want to only call one of those methods and that decision is to be made at runtime?

Then you don't combine them together, basically. For example:

```
// Names changed to be more conventional

SampleDelegate s1 = someCondition
    ? new SampleDelegate(SampleMethod)
    : new SampleDelegate(SampleMethod2);
// This will call either SampleMethod or SampleMethod2, depending on condition
s1();
```

Note that normally I'd use a method group conversion, but you can't use method groups for the second and third operands of the conditional operator. You could use:

```
SampleDelegate s1;
if (condition) {
    s1 = SampleMethod;
} else {
    s2 = SampleMethod2;
}
```

... or

```
SampleDelegate s1 = someCondition
    ? new SampleDelegate(SampleMethod)
    : SampleMethod2;
```

Neither of these looks particularly nice to me though.

Comment: so what you are saying is it is not possible to use delegates without if/else or switch-case for choosing the particular method to run?

Comment: @AnoopDV: I'm not sure what you're asking. You've got to use a condition *somewhere*, yes... how else do you expect to choose between multiple options? That condition could be expressed in a number of ways...